# Difference between a Transfer Function and the same transfer function generated using syslin command in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I have defined a transfer function G1 = n1 / d1 where n1 and d1 are polynomials in s. According to the Scilab reference manual, a continuous linear system namely "sys" can be defined using the command **syslin** using the syntax sys = syslin('c', G1) but then what is the real difference between the transfer function **G1** and the transfer function **sys**, both seems to be same in every aspect and I couldn't really understand the actual difference the function syslin created on the transfer function G1. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

G1 is the representation of a rational fraction and sys represents a continuous time transfer function. The only difference between both data structures is the time domain property (dt) which is an empty array for rational fraction G1.dt returns [] and sys.dt returns "c" if the system is continuous or the time step if the system is discrete.